# Very simple XML reading in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to read the following XML file:

Words.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<words>
  <word>Bat</word>
  <word>Dog</word>
  <word>Car</word>
</words>
```

..using XDocument. I keep getting a "Non white space characters cannot be added to content" error with this code:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument("words.xml");
foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("word"))
{
   Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to load the document like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("words.xml");
```

The reason your original code fails is you are using [`XDocument (Object[])` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352589%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that normally expects list of XElement objects like:

```
var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Root"));
```

Comment: +1. For details - check out [`XDocument(object[])` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352589%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Valid Content of XElement and XDocument Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943882%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) articles on MSDN.